# How to insert into two tables which have foreign key constraints referring to each other?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables table1 and table2. Both have the same attributes id1,id2 with id1 being the primary key in each of the two tables. id1 in table1 and table2 refer to each other. Now, initially both the tables are empty and I have to insert data. How do I do it?
I know one method is as follows:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

This will tell MySQL not to check for foreign key constraints. But I want to insert data and then check for foreign key constraints violation. If it is violated then rollback the transaction.
Basically, I want to know if MySQL supports deffered constraint checking for a transaction. If yes, then what is the syntax? If no, then how can I ever insert data into my tables?

Comment: Looks like a bad database design.

Comment: Changing the table design will be the best solution for you. Since you don't have any data, then this is the best time to change.

Comment: No, I intentionally designed it like this to see if MySQL supports deferred constraint checking. Obviously, such a design would be terrible! :P @Jens